# Where can I get a 'fmaxf' function?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build on Visual C++ with `np.c`.

But I get an error message like follows:

```
Const float d=fmaxf(0.0f, x+3./8. + (b[c])); 

Error c2065: 'fmaxf' : undeclared identifier
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: @EJP I have already did it.

Comment: For C++, you can use `std::max(a, b)`.

Comment: Is this the same with fmaxf?

Comment: `std::max` is templated on the argument type, so will work for anything that implements comparison operators, including ints, floats and doubles.

Comment: @msandiford Thanks I got it. ^^

Comment: @jamji For better C99 support use more recent version of [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx), it's free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSVC doesn't have complete C99 support. A bit of goggling turns up these pages:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh308318.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

which are sort of contradictory: the former puts `fmaxf` in the `amp_math.h` header, while the latter claims that it will be going in `math.h` in VS 2013.

Comment: First link is for [C++AMP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh265137.aspx), it is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Drop: While normally I would agree with you, it _is_ (as far as I can tell) the very function we're talking about, and after some searching it's the only place I can find `fmaxf` in microsoft's libraries.